# Redirect link with query string, but only from specific page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My problem is about that I want to redirect links that contains **specific phrase** and **specific query string** after question mark.

For example - redirect from:

```
http://example.com/first-category?p=1
```

to:

```
http://example.com/second-category
```

I have code in `.htaccess`, that redirects all links that contains `p=1` after question mark:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p=1 [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://example.com/second-category? [R=301,L]
```

But as I said - `?p=1` exists in links of a lot of pages (categories, manufacturers, blog info-pages etc.) and this code above would redirect my all pages with `?p=1` to `/second-category`, what is incorrect.

I need to define another condition (that points containing `first-category` phrase BEFORE question mark), but this code is not working correctly:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} first-category
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p=1 [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://example.com/second-category? [R=301,L]
```

Any ideas how to fix it? I am not sure what is incorrect here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} first-category
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p=1 [NC]
> RewriteRule .* http://example.com/second-category? [R=301,L]
> ```

This should "work", so it is likely you have a caching issue. The earlier 301 (permanent) redirect that redirected everything based on the query string only will have been cached by the browser.

However, you don't need another *condition*. The first argument to the `RewriteRule` directive (ie. the *pattern*) already matches the URL-path. In this example, `.*` matches *everything*, so you need to make this more restrictive.

Also note that these arguments are regular expressions, so `p=1` matches "p=1" *anywhere* in the query string, not just at the start, as in your example. Likewise, `first-category` would match "first-category" *anywhere* in the URL-path, not just at the start, as in your example.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=1$
RewriteRule ^first-category$ http://example.com/second-category? [R=301,L]
```

This matches *exactly* the request `/first-category?p=1` (case-sensitive). Note that the slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *pattern* is omitted in a *directory* context.

The `NC` flag on the condition is not required, unless you explicitly need to match `P=1` as well.

If you are on Apache 2.4+ then you can use the `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag instead of appending a lone `?` to the end of the *substitution* string, in order to prevent the query string from the request being implicitly copied to the *substitution*.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing. It is recommended to test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid caching issues.

Comment: Thanks, that is totaly comprehensive answer!